# Camera2 record Video programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

I have written basic code to use Camera 2 API. And now, I need a code to record Video programmatically on tap of button

As you can see below, I'm using Kotlin for CameraFragment and Java for MainActivity

CameraFragment.kt:

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment(), ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

   ......

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewFinder = view.findViewById(R.id.view_finder)

        viewFinder.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
            override fun surfaceChanged(
                holder: SurfaceHolder?,
                format: Int,
                width: Int,
                height: Int) = Unit

            override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder?) = Unit

            override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder?) {

                Log.d(TAG, "View finder size: ${viewFinder.width} x ${viewFinder.height}")

                view.post { getPermissions() }
            }
        })
    }

    ........

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        try { camera.close() } catch (exc: Throwable) {}
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraThread.quitSafely()
    }

    private suspend fun openCamera(
        manager: CameraManager,
        cameraId: String,
        handler: Handler? = null
    ): CameraDevice = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        val permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        )
        assert(permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

        manager.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) = cont.resume(camera)

            override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Camera $cameraId has been disconnected")
                requireActivity().finish()
            }

            override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {

            }

        }, handler)
    }

    private fun initializeCamera() = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        camera = openCamera(cameraManager, cameraManager.cameraIdList.first(), cameraHandler)
        val targets = listOf(viewFinder.holder.surface)

        session = createCaptureSession(camera, targets, cameraHandler)
        captureRequest = camera
            .createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
            .apply { addTarget(viewFinder.holder.surface) }

        session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest.build(), null, cameraHandler)
    }

    private suspend fun createCaptureSession(
        device: CameraDevice,
        targets: List<Surface>,
        handler: Handler? = null
    ): CameraCaptureSession = suspendCoroutine { cont ->

        device.createCaptureSession(targets, object: CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                val exc = RuntimeException("Camera ${device.id} session configuration failed")
                Log.e(TAG, exc.message, exc)
                cont.resumeWithException(exc)
            }

            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                cont.resume(session)
            }

        }, handler)
    }
   
}
```

Here is the code, I'm using to initialize CameraFragment

MainActivity.java:

```
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.camera_fragment);
    if (fragment == null) {

    } else {
        this.cameraFragment = (CameraFragment) fragment;
    }
```

Kindly share required code to record video programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Camera2Video](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2Video) sample from Google.